# Fetch picklist values through SOQL query in Salesforce

Tags: python, django, salesforce, soql, simple-salesforce

I am using Djnago & Salesforce.

I establish connection between them through simple-salesforce

I have created a custom picklist on Contact Object of Salesforce.

I wont to fetch all the 20 values of my picklist & display in Django.

I am looking for SOQL to fetch values from Salesforce.

```
sf = Salesforce(instance_url='https://test.salesforce.com', session_id='')
sf1 = Salesforce(connection parameters)
sf3 = sf1.query("SELECT Color__c FROM Contact")
```

sf3 will give me values set for respective Contact records.

I want to fetch all the 20 values I have entered while creating Color__c on Contact object. In Apex we can do that, something like below

```
public class PicklistUtil { 
    public static List<Schema.PicklistEntry> getContactColor() { 
        return Contact.Color__c.getDescribe().getPicklistValues(); 
   } 
}
```

I am looking to do the same in Django. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There might be a better way, but the following should work:

```
d = sf1.Contact.describe()
for f in d['fields']:
    if f['name'] == 'Color__c':
        break
picklist = f['picklistValues']
```

`picklist` should then be a list of `OrderedDicts`.

Comment: @schwobaseggl Do you know how to update/insert picklist values through this API?

Comment: @MattW. did you find an answer to this? Im trying to do exactly that but it doesnt seem possible

Comment: @KevinMüller I haven't found an answer unfortunately.

Comment: @MattW. I managed to create a new picklist atleast. explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55537360/updating-picklist-in-salesforce-using-python)  Maybe you can find a way to edit a existing list using this

Comment: @MattW. Finally managed to update a picklist in Salesforce using Python. In case you still need to do that look my answer here --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55537360/updating-picklist-in-salesforce-using-python

Comment: @KevinMüller Ah thank you- that helps. One thing in particular I'm really trying to solve now is adding a chatter on an object, like account. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: @MattW. Sadly I never worked with Chatter so I dont think im able to help you :c

Comment: @KevinMüller bummer! oh well, thanks for your help on the picklist

Comment: Thanks this is the only thing that worked! From there I return a list of tuples i.e. (p['label'], p['value'])

Answer (score 0):

Picklist values can be obtained also directly in `choices` attribute of the field as a part of Model exported by

```
manage.py inspectdb --database=salesforce table_names...
```

with [django-salesforce](https://github.com/django-salesforce/django-salesforce).